# Concatenate in sql teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following code

```
Sel account,
Div,
Modl,
Sub_modl
From table_1
```

Where `Div` gives me `01`, `Modl = 1` is `CS`, and `Sub_modl=1`.
I should combine these fields to have:

```
01_CS_0101
```

Where the first `01` comes from `Div`, `CS` comes from `Modl`, and the last `1` in `0101` comes from `Sub_modl`. 
How could I get this result using concat function in teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat`

```
select  
  account,
  concat(Div, '_', Modl, '_', '010', Sub_modl) as colName
from table_1
```

or you can use `||`

```
select  
  account,
  (Div || '_' || Modl || '_' || '010' || Sub_modl) as colName
from table_1
```